# How to change props in Cypress with Quasar and Vue3

Tags: testing, vuejs3, cypress, quasar-framework

I used Vue3 with Quasar and I want to write testingcode with Cypress!

This code is test input

```html
<s-input data-cy="labelInput" v-model="labelInput" label="label" />
```

and My test code

```js
it('input label change', () => {
    cy.mount(SInputPage);
    cy.dataCy('labelInput', {
      props: {
        label: 'labelProps',
      },
    }).should('have.prop', 'label', 'labelProps');
  });
```

My Error Msg

[image]

My s-input component Element

```html
<label class="q-field row no-wrap items-start q-field--outlined q-input q-field--dense s-input s-input__inside-label" for="f_a3252e86-6d43-46e1-8bcd-38030feb9065">
   <div class="q-field__before q-field__marginal row no-wrap items-center">
      <div class="input-label">label</div>
   </div>
   <div class="q-field__inner relative-position col self-stretch">
      <div class="q-field__control relative-position row no-wrap" tabindex="-1">
         <div class="q-field__control-container col relative-position row no-wrap q-anchor--skip">
            <input class="q-field__native q-placeholder" tabindex="0" placeholder="   " data-cy="labelInput" id="f_a3252e86-6d43-46e1-8bcd-38030feb9065" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</label>
```

I want to test about changing s-input component's label

please Help me... appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the props property in the wrong place. Props are usually passed in to the component on creation, therefore I would expect the props property belongs on the `cy.mount()` call not the `cy.dataCy()` call.

```js
it('input label change', () => {
  cy.mount(SInputPage, {
    props: {
      label: 'labelProps',
    }
  })

  cy.dataCy('labelInput').should('have.prop', 'label', 'labelProps');
})
```

BTW, I don't think you will succeed with the assertion `.should('have.prop', 'label', 'labelProps')` as there is no property `label` on that element.

If you want the "label" text do this

```js
cy.dataCy('labelInput')
  .parent('label')
  .find('.input-label')
  .should('have.text', 'label')
```

But please use better test data, there are too many "label" parts to make a good test. For example the label text would have "this is my label text" to make it unique.